# access that element in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a basic question; how can I access the last element of specific column. in Matlab we can use `end` to call the last element. I wonder how can i do it in R?
let's say:

```
df:
V1   V2
1    5
4    6
8    9
10   11

df[3:last_element,]
```

in matlab => `df(3:end,:)`

Comment: i think it won't need a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `nrow`

```
df[3:nrow(df),]
#  V1 V2
#3  8  9
#4 10 11
```

Or use `tail`

```
tail(df,1) #to get last row
```

As commented by @thelatemail, if you want to get the rows from 3:last_element using `tail`

```
tail(df,-2)
```

Comment: thanks for answering. it is good way.Regard to this, if we have vector we should use `x[length(x)]`. so there is no such `end` in R.

Comment: @Cina There is no `end` as far as I know